# How to translate Session?

Tags: translation, word-choice

In a workshop context, I am trying to verblly translate "Session 1", "Session 2" into Chinese. The first word coming to my mind is `第一课`,`第二课`, but we are trying to avoid the implication that the workshop is a course, it is rather a gathering where the moderator leads people to share their experiences of certain things with each other. `会话一`,`会话二` are too formal and not very Chinese. Is there any better translation?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

第一節, 第二節 /jie2/...

Cantonese pronunication /jit3/

Literally a part, or a section of a whole.

课 "lesson" - sounds too much like a class, where a (group of) student(s) learn(s) from a teacher.

会话 "dialogue" - is not the same as a workshop session.

Comment: Cantonese pronunciation in Jyutping is /zit3/, IPA is /ʦit˧/

Comment: @DanielCheung /jit3/ is Yale

Comment: @monalisa IMHO, probably better if you specified /jit3/ being Yale, because reading /jit3/ in Jyutping makes me think of 噎.

Answer (score 0):

> it is rather a gathering where the moderator leads people to share their experiences of certain things with each other.

In this case, I suggest 聚會(gathering) or 研討 (Seminar)

Session 1 -- 第一次聚會 (the first gathering) / 研討(會)一 (seminar 1)

Session 2 -- 第二次聚會 (the second gathering)/ 研討(會)二 (seminar 2)

- 研 = 研究 (study)
- 討 = 討論 (discuss)

研討 (study + discuss + gathering) = seminar

To be more specific: 交流研討會

聚會 sounds more casual

Also, consider 坐談 (Discussion)

坐談(會)一, 坐談(會)二

Answer (score 0):

Given each gathering *is* a workshop *is* a session:

培训课程采取一系列研讨会的形式。
The training programme takes the form of a series of workshops.

> “the moderator leads people to share their experiences of certain
> things with each other”

(Self-help group maybe??)

研讨会： discussion forum, seminar, workshop

Why not just use: 第一研讨会，第二研讨会，第三 。。。

Doesn't sound too ominously off-putting!